# Python Pandas Split strings into two Columns using str.split()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do you split the text in a column to create a new column in a dataframe using "(" and ")"?
Current data frame:

|  | Item | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | coat | Boys (Target) |
| 1 | boots | Womens (DSW) |
| 2 | socks | Girls (Kohls) |
| 3 | shirt | Mens (Walmart) |
| 4 | boots | Womens (DSW) |
| 5 | coat | Boys (Target) |

What I want to create:

|  | Item | Description | Retailer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | coat | Boys | Target |
| 1 | boots | Womens | DSW |
| 2 | socks | Girls | Kohls |
| 3 | shirt | Mens | Walmart |
| 4 | boots | Womens | DSW |
| 5 | coat | Boys | Target |

I've tried the following:

```
df[['Description'], ['Retailer']] = df['Description'].str.split("(")
```

I get an error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have run this tiny test and seems to work; note the space and the \ in the split string.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Series(['Boys (Target)','Womens (DSW)','Girls (Kohls)'])
print(df)
d1 = df.str.split(' \(')
print(d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# creating the df
item = ['coat','boots']
dec = ["Boys (Target)", "Womens (DSW)"]
df = pd.DataFrame(item, columns=['Item'])
df['Description'] = dec


def extract_brackets(row):
    return row.split('(', 1)[1].split(')')[0].strip()


def extract_first_value(row):
    return row.split()[0].strip()


df['Retailer'] = df['Description'].apply(extract_brackets)
df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(extract_first_value)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the parameter `expand=True` within `split` function, and rearrange the way you assign back your two columns. Consider using the following code:

```
df[['Description','Retailer']]  = df.Description.str.replace(')','',regex=True)\
    .str.split('(',expand=True)

print(df)

    Item Description Retailer
0   coat       Boys    Target
1  boots     Womens       DSW
2  socks      Girls     Kohls
3  shirt       Mens   Walmart
4  boots     Womens       DSW
5   coat       Boys    Target
```

I am first removing the closing bracket from Description, and then expanding based on the opening bracket.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.findall`:

```
df[["Description", "Retailer"]] = df["Description"].str.findall("\w+").apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Item Description Retailer
0   coat        Boys   Target
1  boots      Womens      DSW
2  socks       Girls    Kohls
3  shirt        Mens  Walmart
4  boots      Womens      DSW
5   coat        Boys   Target
```